# I want to have releated three dropdown menu in Angular 10

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

In my backend application I have one function which provides data according to a parentId. From the dropdown menu I get the id of the selected item and send it to backend.  But I don't receive second dropdown menu data.

This is my html code.

```
<form [formGroup]="competence">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select formControlName="discipline" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeDiscipline($event.target.value)">
              <option value="">Select Discipline...</option>
              <option *ngFor="let discipline of disciplines" [value]="discipline.id">{{discipline.description}} {{discipline.id}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select formControlName="experience" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeExperience($event.target.value)">
              <option value="">Select Experience...</option>
              <option *ngFor="let experience of experiences" [value]="experience.id">{{experience.description}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select formControlName="specilization" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select Specilization...</option>
              <option *ngFor="let specilization of specilizations" [value]="specilization.id">{{specilization.description}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
```

this is my component.ts code. Here in ngoninit function gets the data for first dropdown.
but onchangeDiscipline  and onchangeExperince functions dont bring me items.

```
    export class Step3Component implements OnInit {

  profileWorkForm: FormGroup;
  competence: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  public profile: Profile;
  public disciplines: Competence;
  public experiences: Competence;
  public specilizations: Competence;

  constructor(
    private competenceService: CompetenceService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.competenceService.getDisciplines().subscribe((competence)=>{
      console.log(competence);
      this.disciplines = competence;
    })
  }
  
  onChangeDiscipline(parentId: number) {
    if(parentId){
      this.competenceService.getExperiences(parentId).subscribe((experience)=>{
        this.experiences.id = experience.id;
        this.experiences.description = experience.description;
        this.specilizations = null;
      });
    }
    else{
      this.experiences =null;
      this.specilizations = null;
    }
  }

  onChangeExperience(parentId: number) {
    if(parentId){
      this.competenceService.getSpecilizations(parentId).subscribe((specilization)=>{
        this.specilizations.id = specilization.id;
        this.specilizations.description = specilization.description;
      });
    }
    else{
      this.specilizations =null;
    }
  }
}
```

here is my service.ts code

```
export class CompetenceService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getDisciplines() {
    return this.http.get<Competence>(endpoint + 'competence/getAllByParentId', httpOptions);
}

getExperiences(parentId: number){
  return this.http.get<Competence>(endpoint + 'competence/GetAllByParentId' + {parentId});
}

getSpecilizations(parentId: number){
  return this.http.get<Competence>(endpoint + 'competence/GetAllByParentId' + {parentId});
}
```

}

this is my backend code.

```
[HttpGet("GetAllByParentId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllByParentId(int? parentId = null)
    {
        var competences = await _competenceService.GetAllByParentId(parentId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Ok(competences);
    }
```

I get this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a '/' to your links `'competence/GetAllByParentId/'` in the service :

```
export class CompetenceService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getDisciplines() {
    return this.http.get<Competence>(endpoint + 'competence/getAllByParentId', httpOptions);
}

getExperiences(parentId: number){
  return this.http.get<Competence>(endpoint + 'competence/GetAllByParentId/' + {parentId});
}

getSpecilizations(parentId: number){
  return this.http.get<Competence>(endpoint + 'competence/GetAllByParentId/' + {parentId});
}
```

and in your controller add `/{parentId}` to your route

```
[HttpGet("GetAllByParentId/{parentId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllByParentId(int? parentId = null)
{
    var competences = await _competenceService.GetAllByParentId(parentId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok(competences);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it didnt work, even i was getting with original code first dropdown menu but with edited code i didnt get that one also. Thanks.